# Топленный/топлёный

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать?

`Топлённый/топлёный шоколод.`

`Топленный/топленый корабль.`

`Топлённые/топлёные котята смогли спастись и посейчас готорят свой план-месть.`

`Топлённая/топлёная банная печонка была кстати, когда я, холодный-голодный, пришёл из глуби леса.`

Comment: Пжста, уберите предложение про котят.  Оно мне не нравится.  "И зверье, как братьев наших меньших,
Никогда не бил по голове".

Comment: But they managed to save themselves!

Comment: I can't delete it because I can't understand how many *n's* that adjective participle needs, an answer to which you could already have given, I believe.

Comment: Will you let me think a little more? I choose the form of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

1. ***Топлёный*** шоколад.
2. ***Потопленный*** корабль.
3. Котята, которых хотели ***утопить***, смогли спастись и посейчас готовят свой план-месть.
4. **ТОпленная** банная печонка была кстати, когда я, холодный-голодный, пришёл из глуби леса.

**СЛОВАРИ**

**Орфографический словарь:**

***топленый***, прил. (топленая комната)

***топлёный***, прил. (топлёное молоко)

***топленный***; кр. ф. -ен, -ена, прич.

**Большой толковый словарь**

**ТОПЛЁНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. Полученный путём перетапливания. Т-ое масло, сало. Т. жир. 2. Приготовленный путём длительного выдерживания и кипячения в печи на лёгком жару. Т-ое молоко. Т-ые сливки.

**1. ТОПИТЬ**, топлю, топишь; топленный; -лен, -а, -о; нсв. (св. вытопить и истопить). что. 1. Разводить и поддерживать огонь в печи, очаге и т.п. Т. плиту хворостом. Т. печь дровами. Т. камин. 2. Обогревать (помещение), разводя огонь в печи или включая отопительные приборы; отапливать. Т. баню, дом. В квартире стали т. <Топиться, топится; страд. Топление, -я; ср. Топка (см.).

**2. ТОПИТЬ**, топлю, топишь; топленный; -лен, -а, -о; нсв. что. 1. (св. растопить). Делать мягким, жидким, нагревая; расплавлять. Т. олово, воск, сургуч. 2. Вытапливать или перетапливать. Т. китовый жир. Т. сливочное масло. Т. свиное сало. Т. молоко, сливки (держать долго в вытопленной печи, не допуская кипения). <Топиться, топится; страд. Топление, -я; ср.

**3. ТОПИТЬ**, топлю, топишь; нсв. (св. **потопить и утопить**). 1. кого-что. Погружать в воду, заставлять тонуть. Т. корабль. Т. котят (лишать жизни). 2. что. Заливать водой; затоплять. Вода топит берег реки. □безл. В половодье топит всю усадьбу. 3. что. Заглушать, подавлять в себе с помощью чего-л. тяжёлые чувства, мысли и т.п. Т. своё отчаянье. Т. тоску в заботах по дому. Т. горе в вине. 4. кого. Разг. Губить, предавая, оговаривая и т.п. кого-л. Только не выдавай меня, не топи! Т. на экзамене кого-л. (намеренно задавать трудные вопросы). <Топиться, топится; страд.

Comment: Но я не понял, почему комната-то *топленая*.

Comment: Комната теплая, качественное значение.

Comment: А мне непонятно, почему печонка топленная, а не топлёная. И [печёнка](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=печен*ка&all=x&help=1) вроде бы с ***ё*** пишется.

Comment: Александр, хороший вопрос на ночь глядя. Футуристический такой. Мне кажется, кто-нибудь знает, а я уж завтра подумаю) Может, она очень-очень горячая, печка-то, а комната просто теплая.